# iptables - Allowing Established Sessions?

Tags: iptables

I'm learning how to use iptables on ubuntu server.

Can you please explain to me what "Allowing Established Sessions" means and why should I include it in rules?

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I understand concept of allowing specific ports and blocking others

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

block all

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

But I don't get the concept of allowing established session.

Thanks.

S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some protocols are more complex than "send a single packet as a request, receive a single packet in response". `ESTABLISHED` handles transactions that are in process on a single port (e.g. HTTP keepalive), and `RELATED` handles new transactions on a different port that are related to an existing transaction.

Comment: makes sense. ty

Comment: Does it mean with this rule
    
    `sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

iptables will accept ESTABLISHED,RELATED traffic no matter which ports are being used. correct?

Answer (score 0):

With just the last 2 rules you will not be able to use any client on the computer as any response will be dropped. Furthermore use of the SSH server will be unreliable as related ICMP packet too big errors will be dropped.